# What is the purpose of include guards in a .c file?

Tags: c, header-files, c-preprocessor, include-guards

I have been seeing code like this usually in the start of source files in C

```
#ifndef _INCLUDE_GUARDS_C
#define _INCLUDE_GUARDS_C

int main()
{

}

int function1()
{
}

#endif

int function2()
{
}
```

I am confused about the purpose of this ..?

I am aware if the include guards define in header files, but

1. What is the purpose of these include guards in source files?
2. Why is `function2()` defined outside the include guards?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Asking the purpose of these guards in source files(.c) not in header files(.h)

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from including source files from other source files, aside from increasing the probability of your getting your P45. A multiple inclusion guard could be used in such an instance.

Comment: '...been seeing code' is rather weird preambule, have to say.

Comment: There seems to be no purpose of the include guards in the question code... That is, it is an example of how to do things in a wrong way. So 1. there's no purpose in using them like that, and 2. because the example is not how C code should be done.

Comment: @Bathsheba The one-definition rule is stopping him from including the .c file from more than one "actual" source. So the guarded-source-as-header case applies only if you're sure you're including in one translation unit but might be including multiple times within it.

Answer (score 6):

There is no benefit to putting include guards in a C or C++ non-header source file.

I have implemented a preprocessor from scratch and studied include guards about as much as a person can, and that is totally pointless.

As for the function outside the guards, it looks like sloppiness to me. Or, sometimes when someone has a magic incantation, they aren't sure when it is supposed to apply, so they apply it randomly.

Comment: I've not implemented a preprocessor nor studied guards, but I could still tell you that using guards in a source file is pointless (unless you're #include'ing that source file, in which case I have stronger things to say).

Comment: @mah There doesn't seem to be a better argument here than from authority, and little else to separate any answer from a comment.

Comment: I wasn't expressing any concern about the answer you posted (or that you posted as answer rather than comment)... rather I was saying that in this case, authority doesn't feel particularly useful. To go hyperbolic in analogy, if you were telling me that dropping a watermelon from a 3 story building would cause it to splatter on impact, I wouldn't need to hear about your physics degree in order to believe you... I would take you at your word :)

Comment: @mah I see your point, but this is *just* enough of a non-obvious, serious question and there are *just* enough corner cases and loopholes, which are really the original concern…

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but...

I think it could be used when testing the code. When testing you need access to local functions that are not defined in the header, so you include the `.c` file... Yes, it's ugly. Yes, you have [better options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593414/how-to-test-a-static-function)!

For the functions that are not defined in the header you don't need the include guard.