# How to handle static elements with cmocka?

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, static, cmocka

I am using cmocka to do some unit testing on my C-Project and I am wondering how to handle static emelents.

Static elements are for me:

1. Functions declared as static
2. Variables inside functions which are declared as static

So let the function `fut` be our function under test, and `foo` be an other function. Both placed in the file `bar.c`:

```
static int fut(int add) {
  static int sum = 0;
  sum += add;
  return sum;
} 

int foo(int someVar){
  //Some calculation on someVar...
  someVar = someVar * 42;

  //call subRoutine
  return fut(someVar);
 }
```

And let foo.h  look like this:

```
extern int foo(int someVar);
```

So lets go on I'll show the problem. I would like to test the function under test by two undepended tests which pass some random values for `add`. The testroutines are placed in main.c and are looking like this:

```
void fut_test_1(void **state) {
  int ret;
  ret = fut(15);
  assert_int_equal(ret, 15);
  ret = fut(21);
  assert_int_equal(ret, 36);
}

void fut_test_2(void **state) {
  int ret;
  ret = fut(32);
  assert_int_equal(ret, 32);
  ret = fut(17);
  assert_int_equal(ret, 49);
}
```

Now I could try to compile the unit test with something like:
    gcc main.c foo.c -Icmocka

There are now two problems:

1. The function declared as static cannot be accessed from `main.c`, so the linker will stop during the build process.
2. The variable inside the function which are declared as static will not be reset between the two tests. So the `fut_test_2` will fail.

How to handle these problems with the mentioned static elements?

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593414/how-to-test-a-static-function) about point 1. About question 2 I think you are no lucky: variable is static, so you cannot reset it as far as you cannot modify the function to handle the reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @LPs comment and my own ideas I would like to conclude possible solutions:

**Regarding the Problem one with Functions declared as static:**

1. One solution would be to include the source file `bar.c` into the test driving `main.c` by `#include "foo.c"`.
2. The tests `fut_test_2` and `fut_test_2` could by placed into `bar.c` which contains then both: The function under test `fut` and the tests. The tests can then be made accessible by adding the declaration to `foo.h`:

   ```
   extern int foo(int someVar);
   extern void fut_test_1(void **state);
   extern void fut_test_2(void **state);
   ```

**Regarding the Problem with the static variables:**

1. This is not easy for testing. The only possibility is to enlarge the visibility of the  the static variable by one of the fallowing ways:

   - by moving it outside of the fut
   - make it globally
   - use some getter and setter methods
2. Write only functions which do not need static variables to be reseted during the testing process.