# Producer-Consumer Error in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement the Producer Consumer Algorithm in C so that  `producer.c` takes in one character from a `mydata.txt` file and puts it into the shell variable DATA then `consumer.c` will read it from DATA and print it out. The output must be in the same format. All the while, `producer.c` and `consumer.c` gives the TURN to each other during the busy loop.

When I compile the program, I'm getting an error: `error: too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0` because of both `wait()` functions. Please let me know if I did something wrong. I'm not sure if you'd need all the code but I hope this isn't too much!

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "producer.c"
#include "consumer.c"

int main(){
  char turn;
  FILE *mydata = fopen("mydata.txt", "rt");

  // Writing 0 into TURN.txt
  FILE *TURN = fopen("TURN.txt", "wt");
  if(TURN == NULL) exit(1);

  putc('0', TURN);
  fclose(TURN);

  int pid = fork();

  // Program done when turn == 'x'
  while(turn - 'x' != 0){

    TURN = fopen("TURN.txt", "rt");
    turn = getc(TURN);
    fclose(TURN);

    // producer() uses pointer to mydata.txt, to avoid having to reopen in producer.c each time
    if(pid == -1){ exit(1); }
    if(pid == 0){ producer(mydata); wait(); }
    if(pid != -1){ consumer(); wait(); }

  }

  fclose(mydata);

  return 0;
}
```

Producer.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void producer(FILE *mydata){
  FILE *DATA;

  // Writing 1 character from mydata.txt to DATA.txt
  DATA = fopen("DATA.txt", "wt");
  if(DATA == NULL) exit(1);
  fprintf(DATA, "%c", getc(mydata));
  fclose(DATA);

  // Writing '1' into TURN.txt for consumer, or 'x' if done reading mydata.txt
  FILE *TURN = fopen("TURN.txt", "wt");
  if(TURN == NULL) exit(1);
  if(!feof(mydata))
    putc('1', TURN);
  else
    putc('x', TURN);
  fclose(TURN);
}
```

consumer.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void consumer(){

    FILE *DATA;

    DATA = fopen("DATA.txt", "r");
    if(DATA == NULL) exit(1);
    int c;
    if(DATA == NULL) { exit(1); } 
    do {
    c = fgetc(DATA);
      if( feof(DATA) ) {
         break ;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
    } while(1);

    fclose(DATA);

    FILE *TURN = fopen("TURN.txt", "wt");
    if(TURN == NULL) exit(1);
    if(!feof(DATA))
      putc('0', TURN);
    else
      putc('x', TURN);
    fclose(TURN);

}
```

Comment: recommend `#include`ing only `.h` files and compiling with `producer.c` and `consumer.c`

Comment: @yano why is that, if you don't mind answer?

Comment: I dont want to say its _always_ wrong since there are probably legit uses, but I cant say ive ever seen any. Someone more experienced can chime in one way or the other.. but `#include`ing `.c` files is not common practice. It at least cuts down on modularity... now you cant separate `main.c` from `producer.c` and `consumer.c`  or compile `main.c` without those files.

Comment: but as for your error, [`wait`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) requires an argument,, youre not giving it one

Comment: Your fopen's calls have a mode (2nd argument) that includes a "t" (tee)... Which is absent in my ubuntu man page for fopen... what is the intent, or is it a mistake?

Comment: @TonyB `t` refers to the text mode. There is no difference between `r` and `rt` or `w` and `wt` since text mode is the default.

Comment: @Sam: `t` is a modifier for text mode on WIndows, and not on Unix.  The `b` modifier (for binary mode) is portable, being defined by the C standard.  On Unix, there's no difference between a text mode file stream and a binary mode file stream.  On Windows, there are big differences — most notably that a text file has CRLF line endings on disk mapped to newline on input, and newline on output is mapped to CRLF, but this mapping doesn't occur with binary files.

Comment: @yano: You're basically correct that you should not normally include source files in other source files.  However, there are occasions when including source code is a good idea, or even necessary — see [How to test a static function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593414/how-to-test-a-static-function/593423#593423) for one such example.  Such use cases tend to be rare.  OTOH, the SQLite build compiles a single source file, which is built from multiple separately-maintained source files.  That's not a million miles removed from including the source directly in the master file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the info and the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wait function](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/wait.html) requires an argument, as the error tells you.
An address to an integer, to be precise.

Comment: I added an argument the two wait functions are now:

        `if(pid == 0){ producer(mydata); wait(&status); }` 
        `if(pid != -1){ consumer(); wait(&status); }`

Now there isn't an error when compiling as it does compile, but when I run, it only prints back some of the text with many question marks and doesn't run all the way:

`?erhe????e?a?atr?ss ????? motionessupn????`

mydata.txt includes `Overhead the albatross hangs motionless upon the air
And deep beneath the rolling waves in labyrinth of coral caves`. Can you tell what the error is?

Comment: That sounds like an entirely new question, to be honest. Likely a problem with encoding or two processes accessing the same file at the same time?  Probably best to resolve this question with the wait() error an open up a new one.