# googlemock - how do I deal with "multiple definition" problems?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

In my CMakeLists.txt file, I have:

```
include_directories("${algorithm}/include")
add_executable(
        test_runner
        test_runner.cpp
        test_file1.cpp
        test_file2.cpp
        test_file2.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
        test_runner
        gtest_main)
gtest_discover_tests(test_runner)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as these files both import `algorithm.c` from `"${algorithm}/include"`.

I don't know what to do here. How can I have multiple test_files which all depend on `algorithm.c`, which `test_runner` can discover?

Am I forced to put all of the test_files into one file, or to make a separate executable for each? That would be extremely unfortunate.

Is there an alternative? Something involving headers, I expect? Or does `algorithms.c` need to be a library which I import?

Comment: What do you mean by `multiple test_files which all depend on algorithm.c` ?

Comment: I have multiple files like `test_file1.cpp`, `test_file2.cpp`.

`algorithm.c` is a file. Each test_file does `#include <algorithm.c>`

Comment: You should not be including a `*.c` file ... separate the definitions from the declarations and add the later to an header file (`algorithm.h`) and include that. (`int foo() { return 42; }` --> `int foo();` in header and `int foo() { return 42; }` in source file)

Comment: I need to include the `.c` file because I need to access a `static` function in order to test it. Is it impossible to do what I need to do here?

I cannot make the function non-static.

Comment: Have you looked at [class guards](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/c241man/node90.html) before? Essentially you add `#ifndef ALGORITHM_H` and `#define ALGORITHM_H` to the start of your code and `#endif` at the end, which will only have the header be loaded once.

Comment: Don't add `#include <algorithm.c>` to your test files. Instead, add `#include <algorithm.h>` (using the `#ifndef` thing Aplet123 suggests).  Then add `algorithm.c` to be build or linked into your test_runner compile.

Comment: @selbie I attempted this and it's failing - all the calls to the methods are now "undefined references". They were working just fine when I was importing the `.c`, but now I am using the `.h` and they're failing.

Comment: Did you add `algorithm.c` to your `add_executable` section?

Comment: Approach with including source files is not good in *general*, but in case of **unit testing of static functions** it is sometimes *inevitable*. So, there is a little reason to remind that source files shouldn't be included. See e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593414/how-to-test-a-static-function. @DanielPaczuskiBak: Didn't you consider to put the words about "testing static functions" into the question post and into the title? I see this would be more descriptive than simple "multiple definition" problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap inclusion of source file into **additional header file**, which has proper inclusion guards. Something like:

```
// File: algorithm_test.h
#ifndef ALGORITHM_TEST_H
#define ALGORITHM_TEST_H

#include <algorithm.c>
#endif /* ALGORITHM_TEST_H */
```

After that, your tests (`test_file1.cpp`, `test_file2.cpp`, etc.) may include this header instead of including the source file directly:

```
// File: test_file1.cpp
#include <algorithm_test.h>

... define test methods ...
```