# C - Include only specific function

Tags: c, import

Alongside `main.c` file, I have following `my_custom_data_structure.c` file in my project. My `my_custom_data_structure.c` file contains a lot of variables, functions, etc.

I am using `#include "my_custom_data_structure.c"` directive in `main.c`.

## Problem

I would like to import only single function called `foo` from `my_custom_data_structure.c`. I don't need all the variables and functions, which are declared in `my_custom_data_structure.c` file.

Any insights appreciated.

## File structure

```
-
|- main.c
|- my_custom_data_structure.c
```

## Content of my_custom_data_structure.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int DELAY = 20;

int SPEED = 7;

char GRANULARITY_CHAR = 'g';

unsigned int RANGE = 3;


void foo(){
    // TODO: In future, this function will print SPEED.
    printf("foo works!");
}

/*
    The rest of this file is filled by a lot 
    of code, which is not needed for main.c
*/
```

## Content of main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_custom_data_structure.c"
    
int DELAY = 3;
    
int main(){
    foo();
    printf("Delay is %d", DELAY);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATED**: Added working example

Comment: Why is this a problem? If the linker is clever it might strip all the unused code from the result anyway.

Comment: @Gerhardh Could be a problem if you define functions with the same name.

Comment: What do you mean by import exactly? Why can't you just use `extern int foo();` (assuming foo returns an int) in `main.c`?

Comment: @Fusion it's somewhat unclear what you're asking here. You should add a minimal working example of those two files so that we can understand what exactly the problem is.

Comment: You don't include .c files. You include .h files and you compile your .c files separately. Finally you link the together witht the linker which will take care of stripping all unused functions. This will solve your problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky true, inclding a .c is bad practice, but even doing it the right way with an header file would not solve the problem of having functions with the same name redefined in the `main.c` file.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do what you want to do.  You can get everything from `my_custom_data_structure.c`, or nothing.  There is no way to selectively get just one function.  If you want to be able to selectively get just one function, you would have to break `my_custom_data_structure.c` up into several separate `.c` files, one per function.  (And in that case you wouldn't be able to make use of file-static variables or functions which are private to just the functions in `my_custom_data_structure.c`, if you're doing that.)  Also, as others have said, please don't use `#include` with `.c` files.

Comment: Anyway, what you should do is (1) create a file `my_custom_data_structure.h` containing external declarations and function prototypes for the public functions and variables in `my_custom_data_structure.c`, (2) add the line `#include "my_custom_data_structure.h" at the top of *both* `my_custom_data_structure.c` and `main.c`, (3) do the equivalent of `cc -c main.c`, (4) do `cc -c my_custom_data_structure.c`, and finally (5) do `cc -o myprogram main.o my_custom_data_structure.o`.  (Those are Unix/Linux CLI invocations.  If you're using Windows, or an IDE, things'll be a little different.)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to compile them separately. So you have your `main.c`, and your `extra.c`, and you should create a `extra.h` (and include it in `main.c`).

In this `extra.h`, put in declarations for anything that is to be exported from your `extra.c` file.

For example any functions that should be available to other files. All other functions should be declared/defined only in your `extra.c` as static, so that they are not available as symbols to be linked when `main.c` is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't include source files (`.c`) inside other source files (or inside headers).  It's possible (and occasionally [necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593414)), but it isn't usual.

Unless you've designed the `my_custom_data_structure.c` to allow you to specify which functions are to be compiled, you get everything in the file.  For example, you could use:

```
#ifdef USE_FUNCTION1
void function1(void *, …)
{
    …
}
#endif /* USE_FUNCTION1 */
```

around each function, and then arrange to

```
#define USE_FUNCTION1
```

before including the source, but that's not usually a good way of working. It's fiddly. You have to know which functions you use, and which other functions those need, and so on, and it is vulnerable to changes making the lists of `USE_FUNCTIONn` defines inaccurate.  Of course, the source code might have blocks of code like:

```
#ifdef USE_FUNCTION1
#define USE_FUNCTION37
#define USE_FUNCTION92
#define USE_FUNCTION102
#endif /* USE_FUNCTION1 */
```

so that if you say you use `function1()`, it automatically compiles the other functions that are required, but maintaining those lists of definitions is fiddly too, even when the definitions are `USE_MEANINGFUL_NAME` instead of a number.

Create a header (`my_customer_data_structure.h`) declaring the functions and any types needed, and split the implementation into many files (`mcds_part1.c`, `mcds_part2.c`, …).
Compile the separate implementation files into a library (e.g. `libmcds.a`), and then link your program with the library.  If it's a static library, only those functions that are used, directly or indirectly, will be included in the executable.