# scope of static variable with source file include

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, scope

To have full access to all static variables and functions
from inside the unittest i do include the c-file in the unittest c-file.

I use gcc-11.2.1 and the target is a small microcontroller stm32L0

Now i have same strange behaviour where i have two instances of
the static object `my` and therefore also from `my.var`

However in this small example everything works like expected and there is only one instance of the object `my` and the unittest passes with no errors, but in my much bigger development project i have debugged that the compiler uses two different instances.
Unfortunatly i cannot upload my development project so i tried to minimize the sourcecode to the relevant part for this question.

*source of buildingblock.h*

```
#ifndef __BUILDINGBLOCK_H
#define __BUILDINGBLOCK_H

#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t pub_getVar();

#endif
```

*source of buildingblock.c*

```
#include "buildingblock.h"

typedef struct{
    uint8_t var;
}my_t;

static my_t my = {
    .var = 0
};

static uint8_t getVar(){
  return my.var;
}

#ifndef YES_TESTCODE

uint8_t pub_getVar(){
    return my.var;
}

#endif
```

*source of unittest.h*

```
#ifndef __UNITTEST_H
#define __UNITTEST_H


// This define can be used to handle special handling for the test code.
// E.g. public variables/functions cannot be defined in the unit test, otherwise the linker generates an error message because of a duplicate function definition.
#define YES_TESTCODE

void ut_run();

#endif
```

*source of unittest.c*

```
// I use lib-unity see https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch
#include "unity.h" // lib-unit header
#include "unittest.h"
#include "buildingblock.c"


// increment of a static variable
static void test(){

  my.var++;
  uint8_t ret = getVar();

  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(1,ret);
}

// calls this from your main
void ut_run()
{
    pub_getVar();
    UNITY_BEGIN();
    RUN_TEST(test);
    UNITY_END();
}
```

For my development-project i have to exclude buildingblock.c from the build
and only include the c-file. Than i have ony one instance of the object `my` and i can test as expected.

Does anybody know why i have two instances in my more complex development project ? I understand that the compiler could have problems with the scope but i also get no errors or warnings but the buggy result.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Please update your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Yes this should work as long as you don't compile buildingblock.c, includes in C is just copy pasting the contents of the included file at the location of the include.

Comment: Did you show us the whole code?

Comment: Including C files is a bad idea.

Comment: _Any risks...?_.  Including a `.c` file into another `.c`  is legal, but not common.  From a maintainability perspective (where someone else will be expected to come in cold and make sense of what the code is doing) I think there would be increased chances for decisions being made that are incongruous with the original intent of the code.

Comment: @0___________ it's common practice when doing a "unity" build

Comment: See [How to test a `static` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/593414/15168) for circumstances where it may be legitimate to include a C source file inside another.  There are limits to what that can do — it is an extraordinary scenario, not something to practice routinely.  Most notably, if both the including file and the included file try to define the same `static` variable or function, there will be conflicts with the combo that would be absent if the files were compiled separately.  This is somewhat tangential to the OP's question.

Comment: With the code as shown, the optimizer would (legitimately) omit the call to `getVar()` because calling it cannot affect the state of the computation.  If you printed the returned value, or modified the `test()` function to return it, you might see different results.  If compiled without optimization and run in a debugger, you might be able to see `ret` containing `1` after the call, but make sure you are looking after the call, not before.  Maybe your minimization was a bit too thorough.

Comment: Can someone please reopen this question ?
I edited it and included new source-code.