# Can C include use macros?

Tags: c, include

I want to `include` the result of a macro expansion. It seems `include` only knows <> ""?

This fails:

```
#define audio sinwave

#ifdef audio
#include audio".c"
/*#include "sinwave.c"*/
#endif
```

But this works:

```
#ifdef audio
        if(i==0){set_audio((char *)audio);return;}
#endif
```

Comment: what does set_audio() do? I guess what you are trying to do is conditional inclusion. If your included code is big then you can conditionally link to it in your build script(like Makefiles). If your code is small, then why put it in another file when you can replace it with macros or inline function.

Comment: Maybe explain why you want to do this?

Comment: this c only contain an array, the name of array is same as file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#define audio audio

#define FF(X) #X
#define F(X) FF(X.c)

#ifdef audio
#include F(audio)
#endif
```

that is you'd have to append the `.c` before you place everything into a string. The usual concatenation `"audio" ".c" -> "audio.c"` of adjacent strings happens in a later compilation phase than preprocessing, so an `#include` directive cannot deal with this.

Comment: #define FF(X) #X
#define F(X) FF(X.c)

#define audio_array_name hello
#ifdef audio_array_name
#include F(audio_array_name)
#endif
#ifdef audio_array_name
  if(i==0){set_audio((char *)audio_array_name);return;}
#endif
.... it works. great...

Comment: @eexpress, if this answer suits you, you could simply "accept" it, there must be a special button for that somewhere.

Comment: i find that green tick. :D

Answer (score 1):

No. Preprocessor directives cannot be used like this. You can use macros to concatenate and stringify names, but that's another case. If you need this, you should most probably re-think your design because it's not good enough at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not clear to me... But I see a few different questions that you're asking...

I think your asking if you can include source files, yes you can, but its not the best idea; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232693/including-one-c-source-file-in-another) for a good discussion why.

If you're wondering about including files with "..." vs <...>, the difference is the quotes are when files are in your local directory (or you want to include the path to the file) the <> are for when the file is in your search path.

If you want to stringify the file name, then 
Jens Guestedt answer is what you want... But I question the logic behind doing this...

Why not include the .c file in your project normally (add it to your makefile or whatever) then just wrap the code in question (or the while file) in the #ifdef? That's a much more standard way to conditionally compile the code.

Comment: sometimes, i want modify only one word, all codes need not change. just this. thanks.