# the use of '"#include" in c and this link error?

Tags: c, visual-c++, include, visual-c++-6

why can't I use `#include "getline.c"` or `strindex.c` in vc 6.0?

```
                              -----test30src.c------

#include <stdio.h>
#include "getline.c"
#include "strindex.c"

#define MAXLINE 1000

char pattern[] = "ould";

int main()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int found = 0;
    while(getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
        if(strindex(line, pattern) >= 0){
            printf("%s", line);
            found++;
        }

    return found;
}

                                ------getline.c------
#include <stdio.h>

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    i = 0;

    while(--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if(c=='\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
                               -----strindex.c-----
int strindex(char s[], char t[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        for(j = i, k = 0; s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
            ;
        if(k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
            return j;
    }

    return -1;

}
```

Error:

```
--------------------Configuration: test30 - Win32 Debug--------------------
Linking...
getline.obj : error LNK2005: _getline already defined in test30src.obj
strindex.obj : error LNK2005: _strindex already defined in test30src.obj
Debug/test30.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Comment: Why are you `#include`-ing **.c** files, rather than **.h** files?

Comment: I think `#include` will just copy the `.c` files? Is it right?

Comment: getline.obj and strindex.obj is not necessary case to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You should include string.h instead of getline.c

Answer (score 1):

You must not include files which contain definitions, or you  will end up with multiple instances of the same functions. Create header file which contains only declarations.

**getline.c** (definitions)

```
#include "getline.h"
int getline(char s[], int lim) { ... }
```

**getline.h** (only declarations)

```
#ifndef GETLINE_H    
#define GETLINE_H
int getline(char s[], int lim);
#endif
```

**main.c** (include only header)

```
#include "getline.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

Most IDEs will compile all .c files by default. Here, it will compile once `getline.c`
and `strindex.c` by themselves, and a second time when it compiles `testsrc30.c`, which include the two other files. Remember that the `#include` directive simply copy the contents of the included file.

At the time of linking, some symbols are found twice, and the linker can't handle the ambiguity-

The standard way of using `#include`'s is with header (.h) files containing the declarations for your functions.

Example

```
//getline.h

#ifndef GETLINE_H  //Header guard - avoid multiple inclusion
#define GETLINE_H
#include <stdio.h>

int getline(char s[], int lim); //function declaration

#endif // GETLINE_H
```

.

```
//getline.c

#include "getline.h"

int getline(char s[], int lim)  //declaration
{
    // Implement whatever your function does
}
```

.

```
// test30src.c
#include "getline.h"

int main(void)
{
    // Put your code here
}
```

In some cases, it might be tolerable to include .c files. But in this case, you should make sure that these .c files are not compiled by themselves and linked. See this related question : [Including one C source file in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232693/including-one-c-source-file-in-another)

Answer (score -1):

you can include c files like this but make sure to put those files in the same directory or else give full path.

```
#include "complete_path/getline.c"
```

this will work

Comment: Reread the question and the other answers: including C files leads to linker errors.