# I have 2 issues with includes

Tags: c, eclipse

I am programming in CCS (based on Eclipse) to learn to use microcontrollers.

I'm having some problems with includes.

---

I have 4 files:

**GPIO.h** - macros and prototypes of GPIO functions

**GPIO.c** - implementation of GPIO functions declared in GPIO.h

**main.c** - main program

**util.h** - macros and typedefs essential to all other files

---

In each of the programs put the includes, I ctrl + c / ctrl + v of my code:
*I really try with " ", I would like to make my code run, it would be rewarding.*

```
GPIO.h - #include "util.h"

GPIO.c - #include "GPIO.h"

main.c - #include "GPIO.c"

util.h - (no includes)
```

As in eclipse all files are placed in the project folder. Already checked manually by accessing the folder, and they are there.

When I compile and run, there are 2 errors referring to include:

```
"../GPIO.c", Line 9: fatal error # 1965: Can not open source file "GPIO.h"

"../main.c", Line 1: fatal error # 1965: Can not open source file "GPIO.c"
```

I do not understand what's wrong!

I made the edit so that people understand that even with "" the error continues (@ mame98). I made it clear that I am using the CCS IDE based on Eclipse and now my suspicion is with the operating system. I will have the opportunity to test on Windows only now.

Comment: Try using `""` instead of `<>`. And *never* include `*.c` files.

Comment: In main I need include GPIO.h and util.h?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/349148

Comment: Depends. If it needs the stuff defined there.

Comment: @EugeneSh. including `*.c` files is allowed in C. Though not a good practice. read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109255/978399

Comment: @jada12276 `a=b++ + ++b` is allowed as well. Not everything allowed should be used. I can't think of even one use case where `c` files should be included. The linked answer is not convincing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: @EugeneSh. don't work. Reading some forums IT seems that it is because administrative privileges related to CCS software. I'm using Linux Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: If I use "" -> I get 18 errors! (I remove .c include)

Comment: That's good. It means you have a progress. Now start fixing them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If something is allowed, it can be used. The OP problem is not related to the good practice you suggest. Your comment said to _never_ include `*.c` file without giving a good reason.

Comment: @jada12276 You can `include` `*.jpg` files if you wish. It is allowed. But I doubt it will yield anything sensible...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ofcourse you can include a `*.jpg` file as long as its contents are interpretable by the C compiler. I am sure a file extension means nothing here. Meanwhile, including a jpeg formatted file is not allowed to be included in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only include H files as Eugene Sh. Points out... Also, use `#include "util.h"` and `#include "gpio.h"` as they are local files and they are not in the default search path of your compiler. If you want to include 'global' headers (which are in the search path) you have to use `#include <file.h>`.

Maybe also note, that it is possible to add your local folder to the search path with using the `-I.` option for GCC (should work with other compilers too).

For more infos about the search path, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html).

Comment: I use "" and get 18 errors. I understand the problem of "" and <>, above a user sent a link explaining. After some answers entered in the project settings and added the File Search Path own path of the project folder to ensure it is no problem Compiler. I'm searching in the IT forums too. Maybe it's a bug LINUX UBUNTU 15.10 with CCS 6.1.12.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code... You should add include guards to all header files, so you will prevent multiple declaration errors..

Answer (score 0):

`<>` is for libraries like `#include <stdio.h>`

`""` is used for your own files `#include "GPIO.h"`

Be careful including .c! If GPIO.h is included in GPIO.c, too, you could get errors..(multiple inclusion protection is useful here!)

Comment: The errors continue to appear. And with " " GPIO.c even recognize the macros (appearing 18 errors), which is only what owned file:


    #define GPIO STRENGTH 2MA 0x00000001
    #define GPIO STRENGTH 4mA 0x00000002

Comment: Are you include paths for your project correct? Try to choose your current project, select properties and search in "Build" for "Include options". Now you can add a directory path to your source/header files and the linker will search in your added directory.