# Is C compiler able to optimize across object file?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, header-files

I'm considering between header-only vs. header&source design. I'm not sure if the header&source allows compiler to optimize across object files and across linkage ? such as inlining optimization ?

Comment: The compiler only sees a single translation unit. So no, it is not. But the linker can. Read about LTO. Whatever it is: don't do premature optiomisations! Write maintainable code and don't put definitions into headers (except for `inline` functions which should be short functions only).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Header files and source files typically compiled as a single translation unit (since headers are included in the source files). So, that won't be an issue (unless you have a peculiar environment where 
headers are compiled separately).

GCC does support optimizations across different translation units. See [Link Time Optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization).

See the [`-flto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) option's documentation for details:

> -flto[=n]
>
> This option runs the standard link-time optimizer. When invoked with
>   source code, it generates GIMPLE (one of GCC's internal
>   representations) and writes it to special ELF sections in the object
>   file. When the object files are linked together, all the function
>   bodies are read from these ELF sections and instantiated as if they
>   had been part of the same translation unit. To use the link-time
>   optimizer, -flto and optimization options should be specified at
>   compile time and during the final link. It is recommended that you
>   compile all the files participating in the same link with the same
>   options and also specify those options at link time.

Comment: Don't forget to compile *and link* with `-flto` and some *optimization flag*. Typically, `make CC='gcc -flto -O2'`

Comment: so why `-flto` is not the default one ? Is there a reason not to do this?

Comment: @w00d Just like why most optimizations are not enabled by default: 1) it can be expensive, 2) debugging can be harder, 3) occassionally result in bugs(bugs in optimiser), etc. And not users may need it (or one/more of the previously stated reasons acceptable to them).