# Create library from several .c files and use it for linkin

Tags: gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm having problems creating a lib and using it to link a .c-file with a main-function.

I have e.g.

```
cfile1.c
cfile2.c
cfile3.c
program.c (with main-function)
```

I want to create a library from all the .c-files and use it to link the

```
program.c
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: There are *shared* libraries and also *static* libraries. They're very different
things, built in different ways, and linking a program with a shared lib
means something quite different from linking with a static lib. So you
need to make it clear in your question which you are trying to build. Show
what you have tried and what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your program.c (which is main) need those *.c files(support) to make a new library. If is that so, may be you should compile all of them because your program.c need that (if there is a function on *.c files called on program.c files)

I think, you can take a look on this link below:

[Including one C source file in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232693/including-one-c-source-file-in-another)

Hope it helps, CMIIW