# Mistakenly use extern in C among two codes

Tags: c, include, extern

The structure of my codes is like:

passivertm_formal.c:

```
#include "CPML_profile.c"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n1,n2;
    float *p1,*p2;
    n1=1;
    n2=2;
    p1=(float*)calloc(n1,sizeof(float));
    p2=(float*)calloc(n2,sizeof(float));
    CPML_profile(p1,p2);
    ...
}
```

CPML_profile.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void CPML_profile(float *p1, float *p2)
{
  extern int n1,n2;
  ...
}
```

But when I compile the two codes, error shows:

```
CPML_profile.o: In function `CPML_profile':
CPML_profile.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `CPML_profile'
passivertm_formal.o:passivertm_formal.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
passivertm_formal.o: In function `CPML_profile':
passivertm_formal.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `n1'
passivertm_formal.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `n2'
CPML_profile.o: In function `CPML_profile':
CPML_profile.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `n1'
CPML_profile.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `n2'
```

Can anybody figure out why it happens?

Comment: Don't include `.c` files, or if you do, do it only once and don't compile it independently.

Comment: And `n1` and `n2` are local to main, you can't access them from anywhere else. Pass them as parameters.

Comment: `p1=(float*)calloc(n1,sizeof(float));
p1=(float*)calloc(n2,sizeof(float));` copy paste typo: you're not allocating `p2` at all.

Comment: @Mat So you mean if I keep `include "CPML_profile.c"` in code 1, I should only compile `passivertm_formal.c` in my `Makefile`?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't include the `.c` file, just create a `.h` file with the function prototype:

```
#include "CPML_profile.h"
```

the .h contains:

```
#pragma once
void CPML_profile(<... function parameters ...>);
```

Now, `n1` and `n2` aren't global variables. They're local variables from the `main` procedure (which is no different from another procedure besides the fact that this is your program entrypoint), you cannot access them from another procedure or file.

Move the declaration of `n1` and `n2` to the global scope (but I wouldn't recommend that solution)

```
int n1,n2;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
```

in your case, why not passing them as parameters, since you're already passing the array of floats:

```
p1=calloc(n1,sizeof(float));
p2=calloc(n2,sizeof(float));  # BTW: another issue: you're not allocating p2 but p1 twice: ouch!!
CPML_profile(p1,p2,n1,n2);
```

now:

```
void CPML_profile(float *p1, float *p2, int n1, int n2)
{
```

This solution is way cleaner, and allows to use the function in a multithreaded environment/without needing global symbols for `n1` and `n2`

Misc advice: compiling with warnings on would probably have revealed that you were using `p2` uninitialized.

Comment: Thank you. I correct my code as your suggestions. But still have an error: `CPML_profile.o: In function `CPML_profile':
CPML_profile.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `CPML_profile'
passivertm_formal.o:passivertm_formal.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [passivertm] Error 1`. Is it the "include" problem?

Comment: aah see my edit. Don't include the .c file, but a header file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232693/including-one-c-source-file-in-another