# How to import /kernel/sys.c in LKM?

Tags: c, linux, include

I am a student who is new to the world of Linux and C. I am doing a bit of kernel programming, but I don't know how to import sys.c, since it's not in the include directory.

Specifically, I need it to use the `getrusage` function within my code. Is it possible/ok to include it, and if so how?

Comment: You don't normally include `.c` files. If you're looking for the linux development headers, you can normally find these at `/usr/src/linux-headers{some version name}` - but if you're actually doing kernel development you're probably trying to compile a modified linux kernel, in which case it wouldn't make sense to do that. Can you elaborate what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to build a module you can load into an existing kernel, or are you building a whole new kernel from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include include/linux/resource.h file where the declaration of the function resides. In this case should not include the .c file where you have the definition of the function. [Read about #including .c file here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232693/including-one-c-source-file-in-another)